# Implode multidimensional array to mysql

Tags: mysql, multidimensional-array, implode

this is a code of a shopping cart i'm trying to make. 
the cart displays the products with: name, size, price, quantity and total.
When checked out it saves on Mysql DB.

it saves like this:

```
user_1 | pants   | XL | 10 $ | 1 | 10 $ | 
user_1 | t-shirt | L  | 5  $ | 2 | 10 $ |
user_2 | socks   | 8  | 7 $  | 5 | 35 $ |
```

it's creating  new row for each product for the same user. But what i need is this:

```
user_1 | pants, t-shirt   | XL, L | 10, 5 $ | 1, 2 | 20 $ | 
user_2 |      socks       |    8  |    7  $ |    5 | 35 $ |
user_3 | t-shirt, hat     | M, S  | 5, 10 $ | 1, 1 | 15 $ |
```

for the same user he implodes the data in the column of the same row.

code:

```
   $products_array[$i] = array("user" => $user, "product" => $name_product, 
   "size" => $size, "price" => $price, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'], 
   "total" => $cartTotal);


   if (isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) && count($products_array) > 0 && isset($_POST['addOrder'])) {

foreach ($products_array as $product) {
$user = $_SESSION["user"];
$name_product = $product['name_product'];
$size = $product['size'];
$price = $product['price'];
$quantity = $product['quantity'];
$cartTotal = $product['total'];

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,"INSERT INTO shop (user, product, size, price, quantity, total, date) 
                            VALUES('$user','$name_product','$size','$price','$quantity','$cartTotal',now())");
          header("location: shop_cart.php");
            }
        }
```

So i been googling arround, and found that what i need is a implode function. But my problem is where and how to set it right. I have tried some code already but it doesnt work.

Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: It's really bad practice to try to combine multiple "order line items" into a single order row. I'd recommend having two tables: 1) {order} which contains `order_id`, `user`, `date`. And 2) {order_items} which contains `order_id`, `product`, `size`, `price`, `quantity`. Note that both tables contain a `order_id` column which is used to reference one table from the other. Also, you don't need a `total` column since `total` is basically just price * quantity.

Comment: So in table nº 2) would go:
 order_id(1), Product(t-shirt)... 
 order_id(1), product(hat)...
..My objective is not to flood the table with many rows with the same purchase.